# Table of value of a function with Pythontex

Tags: pythontex

I'm working of making a table of value of a function:

```
\documentclass[french,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{array, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}
\begin{pycode}
import math
def f(x):
   b= math.log(x)
   c= round(b,3)
   return c
lo, hi = 1, 10
k=hi+1
print(r"\begin{tabular}{|*{k}{c|}")
print(r"\hline")
print(r"$x$")
ligneH=""
ligneB=""
for m in range(lo, hi + 1):
    ligneH=str(m)
    print("&"+ligneH)
print(r"\\")
print(r"\hline")
print(r"$f(x)$")
for m in range(lo, hi + 1):  
    ligneB=str(f(m))
    print("&"+ligneB)
print(r"\\")
print(r"\hline")
print(r"\end{tabular}")
\end{pycode}

\end{document}
```

I don't understand why it didn't work (I've got because when I export the py code manually , it's ok).

I've got a lot of error messages at the third compilation with pdflatex 
thanks a lot for reading me ;-)

My setup is:

- Windows 8
- TeX Live 2015
- TeXstudio

Answer (score 2):

The error messages are because the LaTeX code is wrong. Your python generates 2 lines, but there are 11 items in it. Your `\tabular` statement doesn't have 11 columns.  You are outputting a literal "k" instead of the value of k .  You're also missing a `}` at the end of the `\tabular`.

Comment: ok i think i understand i replace by :debTab=r"\begin{tabular}{|*{"+str(k)+"}{c|}}"
print(debTab) ..............and it works thanks a lot @bill N